# ImageArray not populating when the fields are passed to it

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, android-studio

So I have an imageArray it finds the 17 fields. But will not populate them to an Array at the end. It says the image array is empty. My debugger shows that the log is populated with 17 fields from the database. But the array fails to include them @

```
imageArray.add(rn);
```

Java onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myreceipts);

    ReceiptsOperations ro = new ReceiptsOperations(this);

    List<Receipt> receipts = ro.getReceipts();
    for(Receipt rn : receipts){
        String log = "RECEIPTID:" + rn.getReceiptID() + "RECEIPTURI:" + rn.getReceiptURI();

        Log.d("Result: ", log);
        imageArray.add(rn);

    }
```

Receipt List initialised

```
public List<Receipt>getReceipts() {
    // This code will retrieve all images from database.
    List<Receipt> receiptList = new ArrayList<Receipt>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT* FROM receipts_table ORDER BY receipt_ID";
    // Check all rows and add to list.
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            Receipt receipt = new Receipt();
            receipt.setReceiptID(new String(cursor.getString(0)));
            receipt.setReceiptURI(new String(cursor.getString(2)));
            receiptList.add(receipt);
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    return receiptList;
}
```

Comment: Whats the type of `imageArray`?

Comment: ArrayList<Receipt> imageArray = new ArrayList<Receipt>();

Comment: Can you show more code, show where you initialize the array and where you are checking if it is populated

Comment: Ive added the code for the list. Where it is built. As I mentioned the Log file shows all of the database fields and they load properly.

Comment: Is there any further help on this, or any further information you need?

Comment: Still havent found a solution for this, has anyone else experienced this before?

Comment: Could you also post the code where you create the 'imageArray'.

Comment: Is it not strange that you're just loading the Receipts in the 'imageArray'? Should you not add the Image property on the receipt to the array instead of the Receipt itself?